# Batch with "close cmd.exe and then re-execute" in timed loop

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file to run an application (I used to write some basic code in the 80s in DOS), and I need it to "re-execute" the application every x hours. The thing I cannot find is how to "close" (or stop) the application before running the code again, so it wont keep opening several cmd.exe windows with every loop. I am a total noob at coding but I know the principles of batch files

My actual .bat looks like this

`setx some-minor-adjustments
application.exe -couple-of-variables`

Then, it opens the usual cmd.exe window, and keeps running the application forever. What I need to do is, somehow, "refresh" (close and re-execute) the application automatically every x hours.

Closing the cmd.exe window is just fine to close the application, nothing more is needed in that sense (like data to save for example)

A friend suggested the `cron` command but it seems to be for other purposes. I also find over the Internet that I should use the `start` command to open the application in a new cmd.exe window, or something like that

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `taskkill` in Windows XP Pro and higher is a way to close an application.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the Task Scheduler is used instead of CRON.

Tasks in task scheduler can be set to shut down after a set time if you can be sure of the maximum duration.

You can also add an `exit` command after the main command if the main command can be assumed to finish (or spawns to a separate process).

Answer (score 0):

```
:BEGIN
start /b mspaint
ping -n 6 localhost
tskill mspaint
GOTO BEGIN
```

This should work on all versions of Windows. Just keep in mind that you have to change the number 6 to the number of seconds of delay you want plus one i.e., the above `ping` statement will produce a delay of 5 seconds. Similarly, to produce a delay of 1 hour, you will have to write

```
ping -n 3601 localhost
```

Also make sure that the batch file is in the same folder as your executable otherwise you will have to specify full path.

**Note:** You can use `mspaint.exe` in the `start` command but for the `tskill` command, parameter should be only `mspaint`(no extensions). Using `@echo off` won't be of much help in this case as the `ping` requests are echoed back and can't be turned off. You can instead use a batch-to-exe converter and create a silent windowless executable. The `-n` parameter of `ping` can be very large but has to be in seconds.